# Which library can i use to create a view of a graph database dynamically on a Reactjs front-end page?

Tags: javascript, gui, graphs, react

I'm trying to create something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dracula Graph Library can be used to create a view of a graph dynamically on a Reactjs front-end page. It is a JavaScript Graph Library.
Read more about it: https://www.graphdracula.net/